# How to prove an RSA ciphertext matches a Paillier ciphertext?

Tags: rsa, zero-knowledge-proofs, paillier

Suppose I know an RSA public key $(n,e)$ and I create two ciphertexts: An RSA ciphertext $C_1 = m^e \mod n$ and a Paillier ciphertext $C_2 = g^m \cdot r^n \mod n^2$.

Is there a known efficient method to prove in zero knowledge that the two plaintexts are equal $\mod n$?

Comment: The main reason why I think a ZKP could exist in this context is that (as far as I know), these two messages are both already ${}\mod n$.  What I believe makes this difficult is that they operate with different homomorphisms.